# How to avoid polling the server for each individual result - htmx

Tags: django, htmx

I've got 3 django-celery tasks running independently, they each finish at different times and take anywhere between 20-45 seconds. I could poll the server through 3 different hx-triggers in order to get my 3 different results as they become available, however this seems like unnecessary load on the server, as I'd like to poll every 5 seconds.

Ideally I'd just have 1 hx-trigger set up which polls for all 3 results and then places the results in their divs when they become available but I'm not sure how to achieve this - I can alter the front end, if needed, to make it possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a single endpoint that can generate the output for the three results, then you can use out of band swaps to replace them all at the same time. Here's an example https://codepen.io/jreviews/pen/bGYmQjx

```
<div hx-trigger="every 2s" hx-get="/poll" hx-swap="none"></div>

<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>

<script>
var start = Date.now();
function getTime() {
    return Math.floor((Date.now()-start)/1000);
}
</script>
<template url="/poll">
    <div id="one" hx-swap-oob="true">One ${getTime()}</div>
    <div id="two" hx-swap-oob="true">Two ${getTime()}</div>
    <div id="three" hx-swap-oob="true">Three ${getTime()}</div>
</template>
```

And here you have more information on oob swaps https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-swap-oob/

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with JS, hence why using htmx but I think I can work out how to apply the above solution to my code, using the link you've provided

Comment: No need to use Javascript. I just added the timer code so you can see that the polling is working and the output refreshes. Also, the `template` tag is there only to simulate the server request and shows the HTML that's used for the response.